# What does "La homosexualidad desde la escuela" mean in this context?

Tags: traducción

As part of a Spanish translation assignment, I have to come up with a new title for [this article](https://elpais.com/diario/2003/06/12/sociedad/1055368806_850215.html), which is called "La homosexualidad desde la escuela" in Spanish.  The literal translation is roughly "Homosexuality from School", which doesn't make sense in English.  Based on the article, I think it might mean discussing homosexuality in school, or starting at school, or something of that nature.

What does "La homosexualidad desde la escuela" mean as the title to the above article?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The article doesn't talk about "homosexuality *at* school".

The article talks about parents being unprepared for their homosexual sons and daughters coming out to them once they are adults.
To help parents be ready, the article proposes for the concept of homosexuality to be introduced earlier in life, at school, when kids are still kids, so it gets normalized and better accepted both by parents and children through their puberty and into their adulthood.

The article talks about *teaching* homosexuality at school, or *starting at* school, or *since* primary school.

Comment: And so a possible title could be "Schools leading the way in supporting sexual diversity."

Answer (score 4):

I believe that the proper translation would be

> Homosexuality **at** School

since the article says

> Por ello, tanto los sociólogos como la asociación de padres piden que **en la escuela** se introduzca el conocimiento de la diversidad de orientaciones sexuales.

Which means, as you point out in the question, that someone is promoting for the concept of homosexuality (or sexual diversity) to be introduced (explained, taught, discussed) **at** school.